# I am getting an error when I ran amplify configure after sucessfully installing Amplify CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

After successfully installing CLI.

```
----------------------------------------
Successfully installed the Amplify CLI
----------------------------------------
```

And when I try to run amplify configure I get the following errors.

```
Scanning for plugins...
Plugin scan failed.
Plugin scan failed.
Error: Plugin scan failed.
    at scan (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/src/plugin-manager.ts:137:11)
```

How do I fix this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What version of Amplify and Node are you using? If you're using the latest versions, you can open an issue on github, which will be responded by the Amplify CLI team: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli

Comment: If I try to run amplify -v, I get the same error. Node version is v12.16.1. Any amplify commands give me the same error. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run with admin rights the following:

```
amplify plugin scan
```

This will grant the CLI permission to access the file mentioned in the error